# PHP-FPM chroot - one pool for all nginx virtualhosts

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, chroot

Now we have multiple virtualhots (nginx) under one php-fpm pool. We would like to use it same way with `chroot`.

Chroot directive is absolute path `/var/www`, but `chdir` should be `/[domain]/httpdocs`

Is it possible to pass some variable (for example `$domain`) from nginx to use it in `chdir=/$domain/httpdocs` like `$pool`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figure it out.

nginx virtualhost config

```
root /chroot/var/www/domain.com/httpdocs;
...

location ~ ^/[^/]+\.php$
{
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;

  include fastcgi.conf;

  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domain.com/httpdocs$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT   /var/www/domain.com/httpdocs;
}
```

pool config

```
chroot = /chroot
chdir =
```

PHP-FPM chroot troubleshooting

1. paths have to be redefined in each nginx virtualhost and passed to php-fpm using fastcgi_param
2. fastcgi.conf allready have definitions for SCRIPT_FILENAME, DOCUMENT_ROOT so directives must be behind include. **DOCUMENT_ROOT default value is nginx virtualhost root !!**
3. fastcgi_pass has to be ip:port instead of socket (not available in chroot)
   (add listen=9000 to pool config)
4. use nginx more headers module for debug to view variables in response headers (**debian package libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter**)

   ```
    more_set_headers    "x-debug-header: $document_root";
   ```

Complications related to PHP-FPM chroot

- resolving domain names
- timezone
- mail()
- ssl streams
- imagick module

https://knzl.at/setting-up-a-chroot-for-php/
https://gist.github.com/nikitasius/7ff0de91e314d955f4e66c76a5c47bf2